# SUMIFS Formula giving wrong result for calculating YTD-1 Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I tried to sum up all the months until the current month. However, the formula is not working. .

I get a 0 for all rows.

Can somebody help me figure out where the problem is?

```
=SUMIFS(H4:AS4;$H$2:$AS$2;"<="&MONTH(TODAY());$H$1:$AS$1;YEAR(TODAY())-1)
```

[image]

Comment: `YEAR(TODAY())-1` is also looking at last year 2021 and not 2022.

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir, alright, i cant upvote daily limit exhausted, so only a silent visitor, noted sir. thank you for letting me know that!

Comment: The Op just needs to remove the `-1` to make it look at the current year.

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir, absolutely, rightly noted!

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir, the one in row 4, will that make any difference, it seems like there is single inverted quotes & two dashes.

Comment: Yes but it appears that row 5 should.  I assume the op is copying/dragging the formula down.

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir, ah yes, okay I was anticipating about the `€` symbol!

Answer (score 1):

In row 2, you show the months as 01, 02 etc and it looks like text as they are to the left of the cell. Numbers go to the right unless you have formatted them to be to the left.

Then your month(today()) will give a 1 or 2 or 3 as the result without a leading 0, which will then not match as testing 03 = 3 may not work especially if the 03 is entered as text.

You might need to consider the years as well.